# Why is the k8s container spec "command" field an array?

Tags: kubernetes, api-design

According to [this official kubernetes documentation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/), it is possible to provide "a command" and args to a container.

The page has 13 occurrences of the string "a command" and 10 occurrences of "the command" -- note the use of singular.

There are (besides file names) 3 occurrences of the plural "commands":

1. One leads to the page [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/), which I am not interested in. I am interested in the start-up command of the container.
2. One mention is concerned with running several piped commands in a shell environment, however the provided example uses a single string: `command: ["/bin/sh"]`.
3. The third occurrence is in the introductory sentence:

> This page shows how to define commands and arguments when you run a container in a Pod.

All examples, including the explanation of how `command` and `args` interact when given or omitted, only ever show a single string in an array. It even seems to be intended to use a single `command` only, which would receive all specified `args`, since the field is named with a singular.

**The question is: Why is this field an array?**

I  assume the developers of kubernetes had a good reason for this, but I cannot think of one. What is going on here? Is it legacy? If so, how come? Is it future-readiness? If so, what for? Is it for compatibility? If so, to what?

*Edit:*

As I have written in a comment below, the only reason I can conceive of at this moment is this: The k8s developers wanted to achieve the interaction of `command` and `args` as [documented](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) **AND** allow a user to specify all parts of a command in a single parameter instead of having a command span across both `command` and `args`.
So essentially a compromise between a feature and readability.

Can anyone confirm this hypothesis?

Answer (score 6):

Because the [**execve**(2) system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) takes an array of words.  Everything at a higher level fundamentally reduces to this.  As you note, a container only runs a single command, and then exits, so the array syntax is a native-Unix way of providing the command rather than a way to try to specify multiple commands.

For the sake of argument, consider a file named `a file; with punctuation`, where the spaces and semicolon are part of the filename.  Maybe this is the input to some program, so in a shell you might write

```sh
some_program 'a file; with punctuation'
```

In C you could write this out as an array of strings and just run it

```c
char *const argv[] = {
  "some_program",
  "a file; with punctuation", /* no escaping or quoting, an ordinary C string */
  NULL
};
execvp(argv[0], argv);        /* does not return */
```

and similarly in Kubernetes YAML you can write this out as a YAML array of bare words

```yaml
command:
  - some_program
  - a file; with punctuation
```

Neither Docker nor Kubernetes will automatically run a shell for you (except in the case of the [Dockerfile shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example)).  Part of the question is "which shell"; the natural answer would be a POSIX Bourne shell in the container's `/bin/sh`, but a very-lightweight container might not even have that, and sometimes Linux users expect `/bin/sh` to be GNU Bash, and confusion results.  There are also potential lifecycle issues if the main container process is a shell rather than the thing it launches.  If you do need a shell, you need to run it explicitly

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - some_program 'a file; with punctuation'
```

Note that `sh -c`'s argument is a single word (in our C example, it would be a single entry in the `argv` array) and so it needs to be a single item in a `command:` or `args:` list.  If you have the `sh -c` wrapper it can do anything you could type at a shell prompt, including running multiple commands in sequence.  For a very long command it's not uncommon to see YAML block-scalar syntax here.

Comment: execve taking an array of words creates a requirement to offer the possibility for the user to provide an array of words. The `args` field does that, which means this is in no way a forcing reason to have an array for the `command` field as well. The only thing I can see as of now would be that they wanted both the mentioned interaction with `args` AND a way for the user to provide all parts in one param instead of having to spread 'a command' across two params.

Comment: If `command:` wasn't an array of words, what would it be, and how would it eventually get turned into an array of words for the low-level Unix exec API?

Comment: Simply a string. If it is `"foo"`, then turn it into `["foo"]`. If arguments are needed just concat the single-item-command-string-array with the args-array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That behavior is similar to the `docker run --entrypoint` option, but that leads to strange and complex usage patterns; consider `docker run --entrypoint /bin/ls --rm -v some-volume:/data an-image -lrt /data` to list the contents of a named volume.  I'm not sure why splitting off the first word of the command into a separate option would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason the `command` field is an array is because it *directly* overrides the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of the container (and `args` the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) which can be an array, and should be one in order to use `command` and `args` together properly (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact))

Comment: While this could certainly be an explanation, I think it is hardly a reason to do it like this. All use cases of the interaction with Docker containers can be achieved with a single command string and the args list, if I am not mistaken.